# Distribution function of characteristic function $e^{it}$

Tags: probability-theory

Determine if there is a discrete random variable whose characteristic function is $\lambda(t) = e^{it}$? Determine its distribution function if it exists.

**My solution:** Using inversion formula for discrete r.v with $\lambda(t) = e^{it}$ , we have:

$P(X=k) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{-ikt}e^{it}dt\ =$

$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} 1\ dt\ $  for $k=1$, and

$= \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{1}{1-k}\ e^{it(1-k)}|_{-\pi}^{\pi} = 0$ for $k\neq 1$.

Thus the distribution function is a point-mass distribution $P(X = k) = 1$ ($k=1$), and $P(X=k) = 0$ otherwise.

**My question:** The result is quite surprising to me, so I just wonder whether I made any mistakes that I was not aware of. Could someone help verify if my solution above is correct?

Comment: Why not verify it yourself?  What do you get for the characteristic function of the unit point-mass at $1$?

Comment: I got $e^{it}$:)

Comment: That's it, then. What's so surprising about it?

Comment: @Ivan Neretin: At first, I thought the result would be some continuous functions:P